# My program always invoke the default servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, dom-events

I have a problem calling a servlet, so I need  help.
Here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.finki.exercise.servlet.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajaxServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping></servlet>
```

I have a jsp page for test purpose , where I amm trying to invoke servlet from ajax

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc('eva')">proba</a>
```

ajax fun

```
function loadXMLDoc(value1)
            {
                var xmlhttp;
                
                var url="ajaxServlet";
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        
                        document.getElementById("mid_title").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", url+"?url="+value1, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
```

function loadXMLDoc invoke the dispatcher servlet  `http://localhost:8097/mavenproject1/test/ajaxServlet`. 
How to invoke ajaxServlet - `http://localhost:8097ajaxServlet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ajaxServlet` doesn't have a leading `/`, therefore it's interpreted as a relative path. So if you send a request to `ajaxServlet` from `http://localhost:8097/mavenproject1/test/foo`, request will be sent to `http://localhost:8097/mavenproject1/test/ajaxServlet`.

So, you need to add a leading `/`. But it's not enough, because you also need to add context path of your application (`/mavenproject1`). In JSP page you can do it automatically as follows (assuming that you imported JSTL tag library):

```
var url= "<c:url value = "ajaxServlet" />";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you quickly answer.That was the problem.Thanks, it works now:)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using a relative link, beginning with the word `ajaxServlet`. Try instead

```
var url = "../ajaxServlet";
```

or perhaps, assuming you have JSTL available to you,

```
var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajaxServlet";
```

Comment: Thank you  for your answer,I used ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajaxServlet lika a parameter in ajax:)